# Using multidimensional lists to store (x,y) cordinates and counting the distance

Tags: python, list

i am trying to create a function:calculate_distance_between_points(point1, point2) where i can get point 1 and 2 as strings in the form (x,y) in the main function.
This function calculates the distance between two points. The function gets two lists as a parameter: the first list contains the x and y coordinates of the start point and the other contains the x and y coordinates of the end point. Then it returns the distance between the two points.
here is my half-done code:

```
def calculate_distance_between_points(point1, point2):
    point_list = []
    text1 = point1.split(",")
    text2 = point2.split(",")
    for i in range(2):
        row = [0.0] * 2
        for j in range(1):
            row[1] = float(text1[j])
            row[2] = float(text2[j])
        point_list.append(row)
```

I'm not so sure if it can create the list I want. Could you please check it out and shed some light on how to make it work?

Comment: Iterate through each list and for each index, take the absolute value of point1 - point2 (or vice versa).

Comment: you would probably be better served separating string-> numeric conversion and distance calculation functions, FYI

Comment: This seems like a variation on an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254). You're asking us how to create a list of lists (Y), but that task doesn't actually seem very useful for your real objective, calculating the distance between your two points (X). Since you *have* mentioned that larger goal (a good thing!), you should expect to get answers that don't really address your explicit question about the list of lists, because it seems like a silly thing to want in this specific context. With luck you'll also get explanations of why the list of lists isn't really helpful.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "counting the distance" and want to end up in the list created. Please [edit] your question and explain it better (and/or show the desired result).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

def calculate_distance_between_points(point1, point2):
   point1, point2 = point1.split(','), point2.split(',')
   point1, point2 = [float(i) for i in point1], [float(i) for i in point2]

   return distance.euclidean(point1, point2)

calculate_distance_between_points('1,1', '2,2')
```

Comment: yes but I wish to create a two-dimensional list of the two points

Comment: well something to think about ... what could this be [point1, point2] ?!?!?

Comment: maybe [ [x1,y1],[x2,y2] ] ??

Comment: just change the return statement with ``return distance.euclidean(point1, point2), [point1, point2]``

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`math.hypot()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot) function to calculate the Euclidean distance between the two points if you convert the coordinate string values to `float`s first.

```
import math

def calculate_distance_between_points(point1, point2):
    p1 = (float(v) for v in point1.split(","))
    p2 = (float(v) for v in point2.split(","))
    return math.hypot(*(a-b for a, b in zip(p1, p2)))

d = calculate_distance_between_points('1,1', '2,2')
print(d)  # -> 1.4142135623730951
```